# What does word embedding weighted by tf-idf mean?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, word2vec, word-embeddings, tf-idf

The paper that I am reading explains about how it implemented the feature vector used for a twitter sentiment classification task.

> The first is a simple combination, where each tweet is represented by
>   the average of the word embedding vectors of the words that compose
>   the tweet. The second approach also averages the word embedding
>   vectors, but each embedding vector is now weighted (multiplied) by the
>   tf-idf of the word it represents.

I understand the first part which is just basically adding all word vectors of a tweet, but I am not quite sure how to get the second one which is a word vector multiplied by the tf-idf.

To get this vector, do I just simply have to multiply the tf-idf vectorizer by the average of word embeddings? What kind of multiplication is it? I am also not sure if the multiplication will work since the shape won't match.

Comment: Could you add link to the paper or its title?

Answer (score 8):

This quote is clearly talking about *sentence embeddings*, obtained from *word embeddings*.

If the sentence $s$ consists of words $(w_1, ..., w_n)$, we'd like to define an embedding vector $Emb_s(s) \in \mathbb{R}^d$ for some $d > 0$.

The authors of this paper propose to compute it from the embeddings of words $w_i$, let's call them $Emb_w(w_i)$, so that $Emb_s(s)$ is a linear combination of $Emb_w(w_i)$ and has the same dimensionality $d$:

$$Emb_w(s) = \sum_{w_i \in s} c_i \cdot Emb_w(w_i)$$

.... where $c_i \in \mathbb{R}$ are the coefficients (scalars). Note that $d$ is the same for all word vectors.

In the simplest case, all $c_i = 1$, so $Emb_s(s)$ would be a sum of constituent vectors. A better approach is to do averaging, i.e., $c_i = \frac{1}{n}$ (to handle sentences of different length). Note that the dimensionality doesn't change, it's still $d$.

Finally, the proposed method is the weighted average, where the weights are TF-IDF. This allows to capture that some words in a sentence are naturally more valuable than others. Once again, there's no problem with dimensions, because it's a sum of $\mathbb{R}^d$ vectors, multiplied by scalars.